# MongoDB C# - Getting BsonDocument for an Element that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mongodb, element, exists

So I have a BsonDocument b (let's say it has FirstName, LastName, Age), which you could access as b["FirstName"], etc...

If I try to do b["asdfasdf"] (which doesn't exist of course), instead of returning null, it errors out the app.  What's the correct way to check?  Do I really have to do a try/catch?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is also an overload that lets you provide a default value:

```
BsonDocument document;
var firstName = (string) document["FirstName", null];
// or
var firstName = (string) document["FirstName", "N/A"];
```

which is slightly more convenient that using Contains when all you want to do is replace a missing value with a default value.

**Edit:** [since the 2.0.1](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_GetValue_2.htm) version, it has been deprecated in favor of `GetValue`:

```
var firstName = document.GetValue("FirstName", new BsonString(string.Empty)).AsString;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the Contains method:

```
var b = new BsonDocument();
var exists = b.Contains("asdfasdf");
```

Answer (score 6):

An update to Robert's answer, the correct syntax using the C# 2.0 driver is:

```
var firstName = report.GetValue("FirstName", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the C# driver version 2, it might not be enough to check the existence of the field. The line:

```
var firstName = report.GetValue("FirstName", null);
```

will return a BsonNull object if FirstName is actually null in the db, when in fact you'd like to get a string.
One way to take this into consideration in a one line code is:

```
BsonDocument document;
string firstName = ((Func<BsonDocument, string>)(d => { var v = d.GetValue("FirstName", null); return v.IsBsonNull ? null : v.AsString; }))(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var GoodItems = Query.Exists("FirstName");
```

and than query

```
People.Find(GoodItems);
```

That way you'll get only the items that has "FirstName" defined.