# MongoDB projection on missing field on Document

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am using new Mongodb C# Driver 2.2.4, I have collection where i dont have all the fields in the document. For example

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Category : Entity
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my query where i am only projecting name and title.

```
var category = All().Where(c => c.Name == "test")
                            .Select(c => new { c.Title, c.Name })
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

My data looks like this

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5575b9351eccba081c144433"), 
  "name" : "Sample Name", 
  "title" : "Sample Title", 
  "description" : "Sample Description"
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5575b9351eccba081c144433"), 
  "name" : "Test", 
  "description" : "Test Description", 
}
```

Now since there is no Title with the document with Name = "Test" it throws error below.

```
No matching creator found.
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link. you should try Query.exists

[MongoDB how to check for existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411280/mongodb-how-to-check-for-existence)

alternatively

[MongoDB C# - Getting BsonDocument for an Element that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628794/mongodb-c-sharp-getting-bsondocument-for-an-element-that-doesnt-exist)